# MFC Dll with WPF

Tags: wpf, dll, mfc

I have a MDI based rather huge application that has plugin Architecture.
The plugins MFC unmanaged DLLs that bring many unmanaged dialog(CDialog base calls).
I am planning to initially only build the main GUI framework in WPF and keep the plug ins still in MFC, and have Managed wrapper dll which enables me to call this dialog in a managed application.

Slowly change 100+ plugin we have over the period of time.

I would like to have new application also a MDI with docking support. So I am planning to use 3rd part libraries from ActiPro and Syncfusion.

My question is

1) How can I add / remove menu items in a WPF application based on the need of the plug in that is loaded ?

2) How will I able to dock my MFC Dialogs in a WPF application as if they were created using WPF.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Shashi